# Why there is no picture preview in another activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to capture a picture and display captured picture on next activity but the picture is not shown in my next activity with this code. The camera is working well and it can jump to next activity.

datalist.cs

```
btnCamera.Click += delegate
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        };
    }
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {

            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data"); 
            byte[] bitmapData;
            using (new MemoryStream())
            {
                imageBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, new MemoryStream());
                bitmapData = new MemoryStream().ToArray();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(camera));

            intent.PutExtra("picture", bitmapData);

            StartActivity(intent);

        }
```

camera.cs

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.image_upload);
        upload = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.upload);
        pic = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.camera);


        if (Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("picture") != null)
        {
            //Convert byte array back into bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = 
BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("picture"), 0, 
Intent.GetByteArrayExtra("picture").Length);
            pic.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

Comment: The Intent object will be bound to the context of the calling activity, so it's not available in your new activity. you would need to pass it through.

Comment: this line : Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data"); 
you can show only a preview with a low quality , you need to access the storage via the file URI and load the picture

Comment: can you show me example code to do it?

Comment: no..the image still cant pass to new activity

Comment: you could debug when you run,see if bitmapData is null or not ,i test it on my side,it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 using (new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, new MemoryStream());
            bitmapData = new MemoryStream().ToArray();
        }
```

you always use `new MemoryStream()`,so `bitmapData` is `byte[0]`;

change like this:

```
using ( var stream =new MemoryStream())
     {
        imageBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
        bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
     }
```